# Assigning object spread to an array typed variable. Why is it possible?

Tags: typescript

```
const myArray: string[] = {};
```

obviously does not pass the typescript type checking, but:

```
const iAmAnArrayTrustMe: string[] = {...[]} // it passes the type checking
iAmAnArrayTrustMe.splice(1)
```

passes the type checking, but it blows in run-time of course

I understand why it blows on run-time, but I don't get why TypeScript will allow that kind of assignment. What is the reason behind this behavior?

Here is an example to play with: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgQQLYLAgTughgTwFwzTpxgDmA2gLowC8MA3gHTNUC+A3ALABQiKamXIwgAHADZxgAUwAUARgCU7IA

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't know which properties of an object are own and enumerable (without a feature addition like [ms/TS#9726](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726)) so it doesn't realize that spreading/`Object.assign()`-ing an array will fail to copy all the array methods and behaviors.  It's a general limitation with TS, see [ms/TS#34780](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34780).  Does this fully address your question (and I can write up a full answer) or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, that fully explains what's going on. Thanks the insight and for the very useful links.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, and I'll try to share my understandings based on the insights from @jcalz in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454271/assigning-object-spread-to-an-array-typed-variable-why-is-it-possible/72454830#comment127994844_72454271)

Because Array is defined in TypeScript as an interface, the compiler can't tell apart which properties are owned (and enumerable) by the actual array instance. So it assumes every property in the interface will be copied during an Object.assign or spreading operation. Which is not true for methods like 'splice'.

Take this interface for example:

```
interface IFoo {
  a: string,
  aFunction(): string;
  anotherFunction(): string;
}
```

There are no differences between `aFunction` and `anotherFunction`. TS can't tell them apart.

However you can satisfy that interface in different ways, like here:

```
class Foo implements IFoo {
  a = 'I am a string';
  aFunction () {
    return this.a;
  }
  anotherFunction = () => {
    return this.a;
  }
}
```

In this `Foo` class `aFunction` is a method in the prototype chain. While `anotherFunction` is a callable property, constructed, and owned by every `Foo` instance.

Remember that the spread operation will only copy owned enumerable properties. The output of:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames({...new Foo()}));
```

will be:

```
["a", "anotherFunction"]
```

Now, given the interface, the class and what we know about the spread operation. Think about this code:

```
function myFunction(foo: IFoo) {
  const bar: IFoo = {...foo}
  bar.aFunction();
}
```

According to TS both the target and the source of that assignment have three members equally named and equally typed. So there's no reason to trow a warning or an error.

However if you call the function with `new Foo()` as argument:

```
myFunction(new Foo());
```

even when we are being compliance with every type check, the spread operation will not copy the `aFunction` member. And that code will fail in run time

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8CwAUMsnAFzIDOYUoA5gDREkD0LyYAFtCnFCiBwATYDBg8QSZKA6dglZEIgxQwMMEwhkzZG2QAjCGADuECFrjoArpPWbSIIQ8xdo12xpA7LNhHZAAFACUFNS0IHQA3N6CrlDufp7BoTT00YQAvkRECAA2cJQKWDjAALYADrkQpeZgChjYeN7IALzIAOSopKWkVKkR7ems7HDIML7%20yAByAPIAKsiYxiAQTvoAnsjF0iDUcJIQlN4Jk8FNxCTI-GBWUFpc8gB0cEPIWRd6owhwufn6VchylBMOVFstVgZNttQHsDkcLvsXNx4hNPK1kGcWgA%20c6XK5GW73OSUZ6vd7vHKaajIUrrVC7MD7JAUBo4NorYxbbDBdJEPRzADKHQeIAA1pR2rI4GBSCc0fIOggQcA4P8IJKgSDHnz2PorDKZPwfmpNjN9AArCB%20Z6FYB0LTGYC-RYgXKbJXlTbtOCS-ZOb2xZFyzTtSkMmnrdBwUUQemw5lobZtXCPVO0uOMg4ZXmEJW7TBVR65TB0AK0qMxjNMiDPIKRXTsB4KYyYKDi0gKCAAD3KVsgQjDlALNeLpfL0djDOrz0DblRmmCdYbsgVPyHyBbbfheaHhdHZcjE6rB2ewcCQSXeibBmLxkoQA) that *explains* the phenomenon not using arrays.

Comment: I would probably write up my own answer as mentioned in the comment.  But since you wrote this, maybe you want to edit to include any code directly in the text instead of only having a playground link.

Comment: By all means! You will explain it way better than me. That's why I didn't mark my answer as the correct one. I just didn't want to leave the question unanswered now that I think I understand what's going on.